# Possible way(s) to start a non-blocking thread that stays alive

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

What would be possible way(s) to start non-blocking thread which then runs a few `System.Timers.Timer` based tasks? Working on writing this code a non-UI library. I
have seen similar questions and the advice on them have been to convert the library into
Windows Service - not sure if that is an option for me.

*E.g.*, `Process.Start()` would implement non-blocking thread which instantiates and executes Timers based functions.

```
public void Start()
{
   Timer t1 = new Timer(10000);
   Timer t2 = new Timer(15000);
   t1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(T1Task);
   t2.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(T2Task);
   t1.Enabled = true;
   t2.Enabled = true;

   // the following is blocking, of course 
   while (true)
   {
     Thread.sleep(1000);
   }
}
```

In code above, if the library call is invoked via WinForm, the GUI would obviously block.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with ".NET 4.0 [c#]: " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use System.Threading.Timer.  It's non blocking and fires events on a non-UI thread.